# JIRA get IssueEvent without creating a plugin

Tags: api, rest, events, jira

I would like to write a script for our JIRA which recognizes Issue Events (when issue changes its stage).

I already managed to establish the connection to the JiRA Rest api and perform simpple queries

I also found the class [IssueEvent](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/event/issue/IssueEvent.html) but I think, that using this is only available in the Atlassian SDK for developing a plugin. As I do not want to develop a plugin (The Jira server is at the IT of the company and they do not install plugins), I couldn't figure out yet, how to detect issue changes by only using the API. Is this possible?

A compromise solution would be to walk through a method each 10 minutes e.g. and check the issue states but I would like to avoid this.

Thank you in advance four your help!

Comment: Hi, what do you need exactly to achieve when issue state changes?

Comment: I would need some trigger that calls a method, in which I would put my code in

Comment: do you have scriptrunner plugin?

Comment: no I don't think so, the JIRA is administrated on a global server of the company, but we need some adaptions for our project so tried modifying the project with by the REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API is a disconnected process, so it doesn't have built-in triggers or pull mechanisms. You could try to use a JQL call to poll Jira every x minutes, as with AJAX. Your JQL call could look like this:

```
project in (PROJECTKEY1, PROJECTKEY2, PROJECTKEY3) AND updated>=-1w ORDER BY updated DESC
```

"updated" would fetch all issues that changed, i.e. new comments, status or resolution changed, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is an acceptable workaround for me!